# Sails.js project using passport.js doesn't redirect to twitter sign in

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, sails.js, passport.js

I am using a Twitter strategy with passport.js but when I hit a certain route such as auth/twitter in the app, it never redirects to the Twitter sign-in/authorization.

My passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const TwitterStrategy = require("passport-twitter").Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  User.findOne({ id }, function(err, user) {
    cb(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new TwitterStrategy(
    {
      consumerKey: "some_key",
      consumerSecret: "some_secret",
      callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/twitter/callback"
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) {
      User.findOrCreate({ twitterId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
```

AuthController.js

```
const passport = require("passport");

module.exports = {
  twitter: function(req, res) {
    console.log("TWITTER AUTH IS RUNNING");
    passport.authenticate("twitter");
    console.log("NOT HANGING");
  },

  twitterCallback: function(req, res) {
    console.log("TWITTER CALLBACK");
    passport.authenticate("twitter", {
      successRedirect: "/",
      failureRedirect: "/search"
    });
  }
};
```

My routes.js

```
// AUTH
  "GET /auth/twitter": "AuthController.twitter",
  "GET /auth/twitter/callback": "AuthController.twitterCallback",
```

The console.logs do run accordingly but the app never goes to the twitter authentication portion.

UPDATE: I fixed the issue, it was most likely an issue with how I setup up passport and not including the middlewares, but now I have another issue of none of my pages being rendered. They are just blank pages and not even the favicon is being rendered in.

UPDATE: I seemed to narrow the issue down to the http.js file.

```
// order: [
    //   "session",
    //   "passportInit", // <==== If you're using "passport", you'll want to have its two
    //   "passportSession" // <==== middleware functions run after "session".
    // ],
    // passportInit: (function() {
    //   return require("passport").initialize();
    // })(),
    // passportSession: (function() {
    //   return require("passport").session();
    // })()
```

Whenever I uncomment that block of code the pages won't render. More specifically when I only leave the order:["session"] uncommented. I think the middlewares are keeping the pages from rendering.

UPDATE: It was how left some of the middlewares out. I added all default middlewares in and now it works.

NEW ISSUE: The callback function after the initial passport.use does not fire. I tried console logging from within the callback function and nothing appears in the terminal.

Comment: UPDATE: I created two small auth apps, one using express and the other sails.js, and the console.logs do indeed work in the express app within the twitter strategy callback. However, the console.logs don't fire in the sails.js app.